# The Mysterious Surgeon

Tags: lateral-thinking

A man carries his son into the hospital because his son has a nail in his foot. The surgeon walks in and says "I cannot operate on this boy, as he is my son".

What is going on here?

Comment: I don't know about you...but I have 5 nails on/in each foot and I don't need an operation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old one, but good!

> The surgeon is the boy's mother!